# How do we pass the data with url while post or get request?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

URL - http://164.100.47.193/Loksabha/Legislation/billintroduce.aspx

So [I want to pass the highlighted data, and want to scrape the result I got.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaGdv.jpg) Like you see in the image there is a total of 13 bills, those bills I need to scrape.

The area where I'm having dificulty is, when I'm trying to do a post request everything seems fine status-wise (I got 200 in status) but when I print the text HTML it does seem to change any of the tags like for example "Both" radio button should be checked but instead it's checked for default.

Some screenshots that might be helpful.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBRla.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS3Xu.jpg), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uNTk.jpg)

Here's what I'm working with.

```
url = "http://164.100.47.193/Loksabha/Legislation/billintroduce.aspx"
r = requests.get(url)
```

I checked the Network tab and got the payload info from there, [click this to see the payload info of the web.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voUaz.jpg)

```
payload = {
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$RadioBttnhouse': 'both',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$RadioBttnbilltyp': 'Government',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlMinistry' : 'EXTERNAL AFFAIRS',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlCategory' : 'Ordinary Bill',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlYear1' : '2000',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlYear2' : '2020',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnsbmt' : 'Submit'
}

req = requests.post(r.url, params = payload) #also tried get instead of post
req.status_code

#Output: 200

print(req.text)
```

After printing the text, in the HTML result, I'm not able to see the data I just passed.

Comment: If speed isn't a concern here, you can try to scrape with Selenium, it would be a lot easier.

Comment: That's the only thing I can't use selenium